# Do I commit all the modified files after a `git pull`?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I'd like to merge my branch into `master`. I've committed everything on my branch switched to master. I need to do `git pull` to make sure I'm up to date, however when I try to `git merge mybranch` I get the error

> error: merge is not possible because you have unmerged files.

`git status` shows lots and lots of files that are modified, presumably from my most recent pull. Should I do a `git add .` `git commit -m "something??", or what's the best way to handle this? It seems weird to do a commit for a bunch of changes that already have their own commits by their respective authors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `git pull`.  It will just confuse you.  Well, I think it already *has!*

All that `git pull` does is run `git fetch` (to obtain new commits from some other Git), followed by a second Git command.  The usual second Git command is `git merge`.  It looks like you had it run those two commands.  In this case, you had it run `git fetch origin` followed by `git merge origin/master`.

What's probably happened at this point is that the second command *failed*.  But since you didn't know that `git pull` *meant* `git fetch && git merge`, all you saw was this weird error where it's complaining that you're *already* merging.  And now you want to merge something else, but you can't, because you're still in the middle of the earlier *failed* merge.

If you had run `git fetch origin`, you would have seen it work.  Then you would have run `git merge origin/whatever` and seen it fail and know that you must *finish* this merge, or abort it, or rebase, or whatever it is that you prefer to do at this point, before you can `git merge` *another* branch.

The `git pull` command is meant to be a convenience, a short-cut for doing the two Git commands, because a `git fetch` is almost always going to be followed with either `git merge` or `git rebase`.  So back when Git was first being built, they made *only* the user front end `git pull`, which used the hidden back end `git fetch`.  But it turns out that it's often quite useful to split the two steps apart, so that you can (for instance) see what you have `fetch`ed.  They made `git fetch` usable by mere humans (well, as much as any other Git command :-) ), and how `git pull` is just meant to be convenient.  Which it is, except when it isn't, like right now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is one way to do it: first `pull` (git will try to auto-merge pulled files then) or `fetch` - then you will have to perform `merge` manually. Commit your merge after it's done and then push all your changes.

There is another way, [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase). I prefer it but it depends on how you and your team use git, so it may or may not be right tool in your case.

Comment: Is there a canonical commit-message for this post-pull commit?

Comment: Also just to clarify, after the merge, my next steps (if not rebasing): `git add .` `git commit -m "post pull commit"` `git merge my-branch`?

Comment: The canonical message would contain the merge keyword (and that is what git suggests as a default commit message by default "Merge (...)". The steps would be: 1. Fix merge conflicts, 2. git merge, 3. git commit -m, 4. git push. You don't need `git add` as those files have already been added to the repository.